# Kik messenger HTTPS issue

Tags: kik

I'm working on a web application for use within Kik messenger. I want to be able to authenticate the user using the sign method, so I'm serving the page via HTTPS as per documentation.

Unfortunately HTTPS seems to break my page and Kik just shows a white page. I've set up a demo page to test the problem and even with just a static page with nothing other than text saying "test" I get the same problem.

The page displays fine using plain HTTP but just shows a blank screen with HTTPS

I'm using a RapidSSL verified certificate served over TLS 1.2 (also tried 1.0), and don't get any browser warnings.

Have I missed something in the documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the website up somewhere? This is likely a bug in your code

Comment: The site still doesn't load when reduced to just:
<html>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>

Comment: There are many HTTPS websites that run fine in Kik. Can you provide a link to a concrete example so that we can debug your issue?

Comment: I was just about to put a screenshot of ssllabs results up (I don't really want to give out the URL as it's on my home server), and I seem to have found the problem. I wasn't serving the intermediate CA certificate which isn't a problem in any other browsers I tried but KIK didn't like it. Hope this helps someone else down the line!

Comment: So this worked in on your regular mobile browser but not in Kik? Kik verifies HTTPS same as the OS network layer so there shouldn't be a difference. Regardless, this behaviour is good for security

Comment: Yep, pretty odd. I use chrome on my mobile rather than the stock android browser, perhaps that's why it behaved differently.